# Check if watch app is in frontmost state

Tags: ios, swift, background, watchos-3

Is there any way to find if watch app is in frontmost (from iPhone or not)? The problem is that when the watch app is in frontmost state, it accesses both the
`applicationWillResignActive()` and `applicationDidEnterBackground()` extensionDelegate methods.

**So how to check if the watch app is in frontmost state or not?**

Comment: Do you mean check is the Watch app is running in the _foreground_? There is no such thing as an app being in "frontmost". Moreover, what you are saying in your question cannot happen. Both methods are called when the app is going to _background_ mode, so do you need to run some code before going to background mode or before going to foreground mode?

Comment: Ofcourse there is a frontmost state (when you turn watch, the face will be inactive and when you turn back, it will appear the last application). Frontmost is neither background or foreground.

Comment: My bad, there actually is _a_ [frontmost app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension), but there can only be one frontmost app at a time, so there's no "in foremost".

Comment: You can check this from minute 27.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/205
Yes, only one app can be in frontmost, but i need to check when this app is in this state.

Comment: I thought i could send a specific message when the watch app is in background or foreground, and if the received message is not one of both, i suppose that the app is in frontmost. But is not ok because when the app is in frontmost, it access applicationWillResignActive() and applicationDidEnterBackground(), so that's not a good ideea.

Comment: There is no way to check whether the app is the frontmost or not. For a more detailed explanation, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of WKExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension), there is no built in method to check whether an app is the frontmost app or not. Even the `WKApplicationState` enum [doesn't have](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkapplicationstate) a case for determining whether your app is the frontmost app or not.

Moreover, when an app becomes the foremost app (right after the user lowers their wrist when the app is running in the foreground), the app briefly goes to background mode, then becomes suspended by design. So it is the expected behaviour that the system functions `applicationWillResignActive()` and `applicationDidEnterBackground()` are called, since the application actually goes to the background mode.

In `watchOS3`, the foreground app has no benefits that developers could take advantage of other than the fact that the system resumes app state automatically for the foreground app.

In watchOS 4, the frontmost app gains the following additional advantages:

- Can play haptic feedback from the background.
- Wakes from the background to receive notifications.
- Wakes immediately upon the completion of a background transfer from a 
  URLSession task or Watch Connectivity session.
- Receives increased runtime priority when using the ProcessInfo object's `performExpiringActivity(withReason:using:)` method to complete tasks in the background.

Comment: Is there any way to detect that watch app actually goes to the suspended state after foreground or background? Like alternative for 'willTerminate'?

Comment: @EugeneBiryukov as you can see in the docs, there's no such method for watchOS

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone, you can check `isReachable` value of `WCSession`.

According to [WCSession documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable), `isReachable` is true when:

> A paired and active Apple Watch is in range, the corresponding
>   WatchKit extension is running, and the WatchKit extension’s
>   isReachable property is true.

Comment: isReachable property have some bugs, i had hard times with this. Also, even if it would work, isReachable is also true when the app is in foreground.